# Matching a generic parameter to an associated type in an impl

Tags: generics, rust

I have a trait with an associated type and a generic struct::

```
trait Generator {
    type Foo;
    fn generate(&self) -> Self::Foo;
}

struct Baz<A, B>
where
    A: Generator,
{
    generator: A, // will be some struct implementing Generator, but the exact type will vary
    vec: Vec<B>,  // Each element will be A::Foo
}
```

I want to `generate` and put it into my vector:

```
impl<A: Generator, B> Baz<A, B> {
    fn addFoo(&mut self) {
        self.vec.push(self.generator.generate());
    }
}
```

Uh-oh!  Compile error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:16:27
   |
16 |             self.vec.push(self.generator.generate());
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found associated type
   |
   = note: expected type `B`
              found type `<A as Generator>::Foo`
```

Fair enough, I must explain to the compiler that `B` is the same as `A::Foo`; let's try with `where`:

```
impl<A: Generator, B> Baz<A, B>
where
    A::Foo = B,
{
```

which doesn't help:

```
error: equality constraints are not yet supported in where clauses (#20041)
  --> src/main.rs:16:5
   |
16 |     A::Foo = B,
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Hmm, no equals.  Maybe I can do this with the colon operator instead?

```
impl<A: Generator, B> Baz<A, B>
where
    B: A::Foo,
{
```

```
error[E0405]: cannot find trait `Foo` in `A`
  --> src/main.rs:16:11
   |
16 |     B: A::Foo,
   |           ^^^ not found in `A`
```

Nope, now it's complaining about `A`.  Maybe I should say `Generator`?

```
impl<A: Generator, B> Baz<A, B>
where
    B: Generator::Foo,
{
```

```
error[E0404]: expected trait, found associated type `Generator::Foo`
  --> src/main.rs:16:8
   |
16 |     B: Generator::Foo,
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a trait
```

Well good work, compiler — it's *not* a trait; it's an associated type, but that doesn't tell me how to write a where clause that matches it.

Comment: Are you sure you need to subtype Generator?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> I must explain to the compiler that `B` is the same as `A::Foo`

There is a special syntax for it:

```
impl<A, B> Baz<A, B>
where
    A: Generator<Foo = B>,
{
    fn add_foo(&mut self) {
        self.vec.push(self.generator.generate());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the answer to what he asks for, not what he wants. Thanks, I didn't know about this syntax.

Answer (score 16):

The trick is to only have a single generic parameter:

```
trait Generator {
    type Foo;
    fn generate(&self) -> Self::Foo;
}

struct Baz<G>
where
    G: Generator,
{
    generator: G,
    vec: Vec<G::Foo>,
}

impl<G> Baz<G>
where
    G: Generator,
{
    fn add_foo(&mut self) {
        self.vec.push(self.generator.generate());
    }
}
```

Since the vector will contain `G::Foo`, we can actually just say that.

The Rust style is `snake_case`, so I updated that as well as made the type parameter `G` to help the reader.

Answer (score 6):

You could get rid of the generic argument `B` and instead of constraining `B`, directly pass `A::Foo` as the second generic argument to `Baz`, but I'm not sure if your actual problem matches the simplified example you showed.

```
impl<A: Generator> Baz<A, A::Foo> {
    fn addFoo(&mut self)  {
        self.vec.push(self.generator.generate());
    }
}
```