# Matching a generic parameter to another generic parameter of an impl

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have this code ([in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1939f1947a6d662c8161)):

```
trait Limit {}

pub trait Trait
{
    fn give<T>(&self, x: T) -> T
    where T: Limit;
}

struct Struct<T: Limit> {field: T}

impl<T> Trait for Struct<T>
    where T: Limit
{   
    fn give<S>(&self, x: S) -> S 
    where S: Limit
    {
       self.field
       //interacts with x parameter and gives an "S: Limit" result       
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to keep the signature of `give` function of the trait `Trait` and at the same time to implement the trait `Trait` for a the generic struct `Struct`.

but I get this error

```
<anon>:17:8: 17:14 error: mismatched types:
 expected `S`,
    found `T`
(expected type parameter,
    found a different type parameter) [E0308]
<anon>:17        self.field       
                 ^~~~~~
```

I thought to use what I saw in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345708/matching-a-generic-parameter-to-an-associated-type-in-an-impl) which matches an associated parameter with a generic parameter so I changed:

```
    fn give<S>(&self, x: S) -> S 
    where S: Limit
```

to:

```
    fn give<S = T>(&self, x: S) -> S 
    where S: Limit
```

I didn't get an error about this syntax but it wasn't the solution of the error above.

Is there any way to achieve what I want to do?

And a side question, what `<S = T>` actually does in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote it, your implementation of `Trait` must implement `give` in a way that works for any type that the caller wishes. On the other hand, your implementation of `give` for `Struct<T>` only works for a *specific* type, `T`.

What about making the trait itself generic, rather than the method?

```
pub trait Trait<T> where T: Limit {
    fn give(&self, x: T) -> T;
}

impl<T> Trait<T> for Struct<T> where T: Limit {   
    fn give(&self, x: T) -> T 
    {
       self.field // does not compile, you can't give away one of your fields
                  // unless you mem::replace() it with another value
    }
}
```

This way, an implementation of `Trait<T>` only works for a specific `T` type that is chosen by the *implementor*, not the caller.

Another option is to use associated types instead:

```
pub trait Trait {
    type T: Limit;

    fn give(&self, x: Self::T) -> Self::T;
}

impl<T> Trait for Struct<T> where T: Limit {
    type T = T;

    fn give(&self, x: T) -> T 
    {
       self.field
    }
}
```

Here, `Trait` is no longer generic, but `Struct` remains generic, and each instance of `Struct` implements the same `Trait` trait.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes this would be a solution, however implementing this changes the signature of `give` function.
To be honest what I want is not using generics on trait `Trait` as this leads to using generics in other traits that depend on it which I want to avoid.

Comment: Finally, In my case using your suggestion in combination with declaring the generic of trait `Trait` as `Self` when I define other depending traits solved the issue.  
An example of defining other trait depending on `Trait`:
 `trait NewTrait: Trait<Self> {...}`  
However I'll wait for another solution, just in case someone else  can not use `Self` in trait definitions.

Comment: I've added another solution, using associated types.

Comment: Yeah that is a nice work around, the only issue is that if you are going to implement `NewTrait` and `Trait` for a type that doesn't use generics bounded by `Limit` then you have to use `PhantomData` in order to keep the associated type generic. This `PhantomData` case gets similar to using `Trait<T>`, at least in appearance. Anyway, it seems that there is no other way, so thank you one more time for your answer.